# passing id from json to js to a dialog pop up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using jquery UI dialog to show more data on FullCalendar EventClick I am able to send all the info to the dialog box I what except I need to send the id and add it to a link like this

```
<a href='editsigning1.php?id="id"'>Edit Signing</a>
```

I can not figure out how to do this I don't what to send a url because I don't what to click on the event and go to the page I what it to be a chose after you look at all the other data.

Everything works except the passing of the id

This is the js file

```
// Setup FullCalendar
(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();



    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        //height: 500,
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 500,
            }

            );

            $("#start").val(calEvent.start);
            $("#title").val(calEvent.title);
            $("#address").val(calEvent.address);
            $("#id").val(calEvent.id);
            $("#hphone").val(calEvent.hphone);
            $("#cphone").val(calEvent.cphone);
            $("#wphone").val(calEvent.wphone);
            $("#email").val(calEvent.email);
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        },

        events: "json_events.php", 
    });
}());
```

This is the dialog info that pops up

```
<div id="fullcalendar"></div>
<div id="dialog" title="My Signing" style="display:none">
    <form>

            <input type="text" name="start" id="start" class="form-control input-sm">


            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control input-sm">

            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control input-sm">

            <input type="text" name="hphone" id="hphone" class="form-control input-sm">

            <input type="text" name="cphone" id="cphone" class="form-control input-sm">

            <input type="text" name="wphone" id="wphone" class="form-control input-sm">

            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm">

            <input type="text" name="edit" id="edit">

           <a href='editsigning1.php?id="id"'>Edit Signing</a>


    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the code that creates the json_events.php

```
$events = array();
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM `signings` WHERE `pid` = '$pid' AND `done`= 0") as $row) {

    $title = $row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'] . ' ' . $row['coname'];
    $eventsArray['id'] =  $row['id'];
    $eventsArray['ordern'] =  $row['ordern'];
    $eventsArray['title'] = $title;
    //$eventsArray['url'] = "editsigning1.php?id=" . $row['id'];
    $eventsArray['start'] = $row['signstart'];
    $eventsArray['end'] = $row['signend'];
    $eventsArray['stop'] = $row['signend'];
    $eventsArray['address'] = $row['street1'] . ' ' . $row['street2'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['state'] . ', ' . $row['zip'];
    $eventsArray['hphone'] = 'Home Phone ' . $row['hphone'];
    $eventsArray['cphone'] = 'Cell Phone ' . $row['cphone'];
    $eventsArray['wphone'] = 'Work Phone ' . $row['wphone'];
    $eventsArray['email'] = $row['email'];
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = "";
    $eventsArray['color'] = "#04488B";
    $eventsArray['textColor'] = "#FFFFFF";

    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}


echo json_encode($events);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me break this down for you ...

The HTML you provide for the link can be changed to:

```
<a href="editsigning1.php?id={id}" id="linkId">Edit Signing</a>
```

This way you can access `$("#linkId")` instead of `$("#id")`.

Now you don't need to change the value but the property.

```
$("#linkId").prop('href', calEvent.id);
```

And since you need to change a particular string inside a string I've used the curly braces `{id}` so you can now replace that instead of the entire property.

```
$("#linkId").prop('href', $("#linkId").prop('href').replace('{id}', calEvent.id));
```

I believe this should work.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to print the data in HTML output:

```
<div id="start" class="popupData"></div>
```

Then in jQuery you would use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$("#start").text(calEvent.start)
```

You can also loop over the `data` response object to add the HTML output dynamically:

```
var arr = [];

for (var prop in calEvent){
    if (calEvent.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        arr.push('<input class="popupData" id="'+prop+'" value="'+calEvent[prop]+'" placeholder="'+prop+'" />');
        //arr.push('<div class="popupData">' + calEvent[prop] + '</div>');
    }
}

$("#dialog").find("form").prepend(arr);
```

This way you don't need to add HTML for each property.

**MARKUP:**

The markup for these divs should go in CSS. Consider giving divs a `class` or directly on the `id`

```
#dialog #start,
#dialog div.popupData { padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; }
```

Comment: Thank you that works. I would give you a up vote but I am one point away from being able to do that

Comment: Is there another way to display the data sent to the dialog box other than a input box. Would rather just print out the data in the box

Comment: Got the hint ;)
Not sure if you want to make a form or an informative popup, either way, both solutions are in the updated answer.

Comment: I just what a information popup except for the link to the other php page with the id

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all the different examples